# Extract data from a nested list R

Tags: r, json, list, nested

I've got a problem with my homework, which is making a data table from API-data about Star Wars. After the parsing I have a nested list with [the following structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GrV8m.png). The list consists of 9 other lists, each of them has four more lists.

I need to make a dataframe, which consists of names of these heroes. So if I iterate, I can take these names by such method:

```
heroes[[1]]$results %>% map("name") %>% unlist()
```

But, firstly, I need to collect also the gender indicator and secondly I need to take this data from lists from 1 to 9. So I tried to loop over the whole heroes list that way:

```
L <- list()
for i in 1:9 {
  L <- heroes[[1]]$results %>% map("name") %>% unlist()}
```

or that way:

```
L <- lapply(heroes, function(x){
heroes[[x]]$results %>% map("name") %>% unlist()
})
```

But I've always got a mistake. So, how to extract this data from the ex-json list format?
`

Answer (score 0):

We may loop over the 'heroes' with `lapply`, extract the 'results' `list`, loop over that, extract the 'name', 'gender' components and `unlist`

```
unlist(lapply(heroes, function(x) lapply(x$results, function(y)
     y[c("name", "gender")])) )
```

-output

```
     name           gender             name           gender             name 
"Luke Skywalker"           "male"    "Luke walker"           "male" "Luke Skywalker" 
          gender             name           gender 
          "male"    "Luke walker"           "male"
```

#### data

```
heroes <- list(list(count = 82, `next` = "https:/swapi.dev/api", results = list(
    list(name = "Luke Skywalker", height = "172", gender = "male"), 
    list(name = "Luke walker", height = "187", gender = "male"))), 
    list(count = 82, `next` = "https:/swapi.dev/api", results = list(
        list(name = "Luke Skywalker", height = "172", gender = "male"), 
        list(name = "Luke walker", height = "187", gender = "male"))))
```

-structure

[image]

Comment: Make it `unlist(lapply(heroes, function(x) lapply(x$results, function(y)
     y[c("name", "gender")])) )` instead of `\(x)`

Comment: @DohamedDesouky you are right.  It may not work with previous R versions. thanks